# How to use python descriptors with default_factory in dataclass

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

How can I make descriptors work with dataclass and default_factory? In the following example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
import numpy as np

class A():
    a = np.arange(2)

class Verbose_attribute(A):
    def __get__(self, obj, type=None) -> object:
        print("accessing the attribute to get the value")
        return self.a[-1]
    def __set__(self, obj, value) -> None:
        print("accessing the attribute to set the value")
        self.a[-1]=value
        
    #a = np.arange(2)

@dataclass
class Foo():
    attribute1: Verbose_attribute = Verbose_attribute()
    #attribute1: Verbose_attribute = field(default_factory=lambda: Verbose_attribute())

my_foo_object = Foo()
print(my_foo_object.attribute1)
my_foo_object.attribute1 = 3
print(my_foo_object.attribute1)
```

the first print works properly, displaying the default value 1. If one comments the first version of attribute1 in Foo(), and uncomments the second, the first print gives object instead of the attribute value.

Using default_factory is important for me, since in the real case I am creating a descriptor for a class that inherits from MutableSequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't do that straight. `default_factory` is specifically designed to provide a value once for that field.

When using descriptors, you need to have a *class* attribute pointing to the descriptor itself. To use descriptors along with dataclasses, the annotated type (after the `:`) have to be the data type your descriptor will take/provide, not the descriptor itself.

If you want default values, since you are writing the descritor class, simply create the value at descriptors `__init__` or `__set_name__` methods.

One extra note: descriptors have to keep a set of values per host-class instance. If you try to use an attribute in the descriptor itself (or worse, in the descriptor class, as is in your code), that value will be shared across all instances of your dataclass.

Anyway, this should work:

```
class Verbose_attribute:
    def __init__(self, factory=None):
        if factory is None:
            factory = lambda: np.arange(2)
        self.factory = factory
            
    def __set_name__(self, type, name):
        self.name = name
        self.attrname = f"_{name}_value"
    
    def create_default(self, obj):
        setattr(obj, self.attrname, self.factory())
            
    # if type annotations are not helping, better not 
    # to include them. they are optional, remember.
    def __get__(self, obj, type):
        if not hasattr(obj, self.attrname):
            self.create_default(obj)
        print("accessing the attribute to get the value")
        return getattr(obj, self.attrname)[-1]
        
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if not hasattr(obj, self.attrname):
            self.create_default(obj)
        print("accessing the attribute to set the value")
        if isinstance(value, type(self)):
            return
        getattr(obj, self.attrname)[-1]=value

...
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

...

@dataclass
class Foo:
    attribute1: int = field(Verbose_attribute())
```

Updated: there was an error in the previous code, where I made an attribution on the `__get__` method - and there is a strange behavior in `dataclass.field` : although designed to work with a descriptor passed as the `default parameter`, in Python 3.11.1 it tries to set the value of the descriptor to itself, if the host dataclass is instantiated with no parameters. This is likely a bug in `dataclasses` - I included an `if` clause to work around that. The default value is supplied by the `factory` callback in the `Verbose_attribute` class itself.

Comment: Thanks! However, I have two questions/comments:    
1) I get TypeError: Foo.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'attribute1' for empty Foo() call, unless I change the default to field(default=Verbose_attribute())  
2) In such a case, it complains during default initialisation, that it gets Value_attribute instead of int in __set__. So there needs to be a case for Value_attribute and a case for an int  
3) Do you know how to make attribute1 a property, meaning make it appear in __dict__ of Foo? now it contains _attribute1_value, but I need it to contain attribute1.

Comment: Oh, sorry - it looks like the VerboseAtrribute have to be made compatible with `dataclasses.Field` so that it can supply a default value. 

I will amend the answer to do that soonish. (If you are reading this 24h from now and it is not fixed, just comment again so I get a notification)

Comment: Sure. Meanwhile, I retract my question nr (3). There should be two names, like in the standard property setting.

Comment: There it is - it can go as `default` in dataclasses.field  - (with a caveat that is resolved in the code and commented in the text)

Comment: Arguably, the annotated type of descriptor should be the descriptor class itself, not the type returned by its `__get__` method. It is what [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#descriptor-typed-fields) shows in the example. If you want to include the underlying type, you can always inherit descriptor from `Generic[T]` and annotate it with `Verbose_attribute[int]`. Also, creating a default in a special call to `__get__` which dataclasses make, creates a static default, which defeats the purpose of `default_factory` for mutable types.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a descriptor to `default_factory`, because dataclasses won't recognize this field as a descriptor. Descriptor class, to really become a descriptor, must be a default value for the field, either by using `myfield = field(default=Descriptor(...)`, or `myfield: Descriptor = Descriptor(...)`.

To check if there's a default value set for descriptor, dataclasses call `Descriptor.__get__(None, cls)`. If this call returns a value, it is passed to descriptor's `__set__` method. If `__get__` returns a mutable object, it'd become a static variable.

*NOTE: Actually, dataclasses will complain if you return a mutable object from  `__get__(None, cls)` call, but it detects mutability by inspecting the presence of `__hash__()` method, so it's rather easy to make a mistake and return a mutable object which dataclasses take for immutable. See my example below.*

To support creating mutable fields we have to reimplement the `default_factory` on descriptor level. We can do it for example by returning a sentinel object from the call of `__get__(None, cls)`. Then, when `__set__` receives it, it'll have to create a new instance of wanted type by calling a stored factory.

Here's the code to present this approach, together with the risks of setting mutable objects as descriptor defaults:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, replace
from collections import UserList

T = TypeVar("T")


# Please don't do this - simple lists shouldn't be hashable
class FakeImmutable(UserList):
    def __hash__(self):
        return int(id(self) / 16)


class Descriptor(Generic[T]):
    # A sentinel which forces creating a new instance of default_factory
    class _CreateDefaultFactory:
        pass

    _CREATE_DEFAULT_FACTORY = _CreateDefaultFactory()

    def __init__(self, default=None, default_factory=None):
        self._name = None
        self._default = default
        self._default_factory = default_factory

    def __set_name__(self, cls, name):
        self._name = "_" + name

    def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
        # dataclasses determines default value by calling
        # descriptor.__get__(None, cls)
        if obj is None:
            if self._default is not None:
                return self._default
            if self._default_factory is not None:
                return Descriptor._CREATE_DEFAULT_FACTORY
            # exception recognized by dataclasses as "no default set" indicator
            raise AttributeError()

        return getattr(obj, self._name)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if value is Descriptor._CREATE_DEFAULT_FACTORY:
            setattr(obj, self._name, self._default_factory())
            return

        setattr(obj, self._name, value)


@dataclass
class Foo:
    default: Descriptor[FakeImmutable] = Descriptor(default=FakeImmutable())
    factory: Descriptor[list[int]] = Descriptor(default_factory=list)


foo1 = Foo()
foo2 = Foo()

foo1.default.append(11)
foo1.factory.append(110)

foo2.default.append(22)
foo2.factory.append(220)

print(foo1.default)  # prints [11, 22]
print(foo1.factory)  # prints [110]

print(foo2.default)  # prints [11, 22]
print(foo2.factory)  # prints [220]
```